# Corrupt colors when Xming is in multiwindow mode

Tags: putty, x11-forwarding, xming

I've just upgraded Xming from about 7.5 to 7.7.0.56 and colors no longer display properly in multiwindow mode.

On my Windows PC I run Xming in multiwindow mode like this:
"C:\Program Files\Xming\Xming.exe" -multiwindow
Then through a putty session to my Linux PC I start a GUI app:
gedit spawnd.start
The application appears in its own window on my Windows PC, but the colours and text looks [corrupted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqpk8.png). In Eclipse the text if not even readable.

If I start Xming with no args so it uses the default 'one window' mode it displays the GUI app [correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvwRX.png), but then Xming has a background that covers the whole Windows desktop.

I thought this might be a color depth issue but checking the log suggests it is using 16-bit color in both modes. From the multiwindow test:

```
winSetEngine - Multi Window or Rootless => ShadowGDI
winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 16 bits per pixel
winAllocateFBShadowGDI - Creating DIB with width: 2560 height: 1440 depth: 16
winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 0000f800 000007e0 0000001f
winInitVisualsShadowGDI - Masks 0000f800 000007e0 0000001f BPRGB 6 d 16 bpp 16
```

From the 'one window' test:

```
winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 16 bits per pixel
```

Is there some combination of Xming settings that will let me use multiwindow mode with the correct colors?